# how can i get file size depending on the type of file

Tags: php

I have a script that scans a dir for the files/folders inside the specified directory.

i uploaded the code to github as it's too long to post here: https://gist.github.com/seby1995/deda163eacb0ebdccac8

if i run the script with $currentDir set to "./" it will show (The script is in htdocs/final1 in xampp):

```
Type     Name                        File Size
Folder   website_data_collecting     10.39 KB
Folder   uploads                     78.13 MB
Folder   test                        8.96 KB
Folder   php                         1.88 KB
Folder   path                        0 B
Folder   db_test                     359 B
Folder   css                         5.41 KB
Folder   Forms                       3.35 KB
File     register.php                5.24 KB
File     recordstat.php              248 B
File     no.php                      2.39 KB
File     login.php                   2.91 KB
File     linkSys.php                 3.14 KB
File     layout.css                  1.58 KB
File     index.php                   2.18 KB 
File     genpage.php                 2.81 KB
File     forms.php                   515 B
File     dir_nav.php                 2.22 KB
File     addtest.php                 314 B
```

when i change $currentDir to "/uploads" it print out:

```
Type     Name                        File Size
File     screenshot.png              B
File     Untitled.wma                B
File     Thumbs.db                   B
```

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for screenshot.png in C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\final1\dir_nav.php on line 39

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for Untitled.wma in C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\final1\dir_nav.php on line 39

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for Thumbs.db in C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\final1\dir_nav.php on line 39

from what i think is going wrong is the getfilesize function in my code isn't converting videos or pictures (DUH) but i have no idea how to fix it, can someone please help me it's stressing me out, been sitting here looking at it for hours now trying to fix it.

Comment: can you show codes in `dir_nav.php ` file?

Comment: Oh! I have got your code. Please debug codes using `var_dump($newList);` and make sure your PATH is correct.

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "screenshot.png" [1]=> string(12) "Untitled.wma" [2]=> string(9) "Thumbs.db" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are concatenating the directory path variable to the filename:

```
filesize($uploadRelativePath . '/' . $filename);
```

On the other hand, if you are calling the script for another file located in other directory, all relative paths will be resolved relative to the caller. In this case, the script file path must be concatenated:

```
filesize(__DIR__ . '/' . $uploadRelativePath . '/' . $filename);
```